# I am using web worker for multithreading. Does Web Worker has own call stack?

Tags: javascript

I am using web worker for multithreading. But I don't know if the web worker has its own call stack or the web worker will go into the main thread's call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has its own call stack and its [own event loop](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#the-event-loop) that runs aside the main thread. That's the whole purpose of the web worker (execute multiple call stacks in parallel).